# Cypress test dependent on hidden field

Tags: cypress

I am trying to test an email address only if it's not optional. I had thought this would work, but it does not.

In my html I have `<input type="hidden" id="Customer_AllowEmailToBeOptional" value="false" >`

```
cy.get('#Customer_AllowEmailToBeOptional').should('have.value', 'false') // passes the test

cy.get('#Customer_AllowEmailToBeOptional').then(($allowEmail) => {
    console.log('text=' + JSON.stringify( $allowEmail)); // text={"0":{},"length":1}               
    if ($allowEmail.text() === 'false') {
        // test email is valid
    }
})
```

I would have thought that when the .then() executes I'd have access to the .text() value. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use `$allowEmail.val()`. There is no text content in that element.